# Reentrant and ThreadSafe function Examples

Tags: c, linux

Please give me small code snippets to understand functions which are both reentrant and threadsafe, as well as snippets which are neither of them or only one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain the main differences, and then show code to demonstrate the concepts.

First, the name is a misnomer. Code is always thread safe and reentrant safe. Code does not care how many threads are executing it since code is immutable. Instead, it is the *data being manipulated* by the function that may or may not be thread safe. It is more easily demonstrated in Object-Orientated code than in C, but the concept translates to C as well.

Here's a simple example using Java:

```
Class MyClass
{
    private int _counter;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _counter = 0;
    }

    public int unsafeMethod()
    {
        _counter = _counter + 1;
        return _counter;
    }

    public int safeMethod(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

In the previous example, `unsafeMethod` is unsafe because it modifies a variable. If threads executed the method at the same time, the result would be undetermined. The `safeMethod` is safe because it only depends on values passed in and doesn't modify them in any way.

Note: None of these things are necessary or sufficient to determine thread safety, but they give you good benchmarks to determine if code is or is not thread safe.